# Putting in MATLAB codes in a box as figures?

Tags: floats, verbatim, matlab

how do I put MATLAB codes in a box or deal with them as if they are figures? Is there a way to do it within LaTeX itself? I am currently using the verbatim environment to present my codes and to be honest, I don't think they are very well presented!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 17):

I would use `mcode` from [Matlabcentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015) for this purpose since it is customized for matlab.

Say, the contents of  `ff16.m` is like this:

```
%%
%Initialization
clear all   
clc
for f=1:20
p=2;                         % dimension of search space 
s=26;                        % The number of bacteria 
Nc=36;                       % Number of chemotactic steps 
Ns=20;                        % Limits the length of a swim 
Nre=4;                       % The number of reproduction steps 
Ned=2;                       % The number of elimination-dispersal events 
Sr=s/2;                      % The number of bacteria reproductions (splits) per generation 
Ped=0.25;                    % The probabilty that each bacteria will be eliminated/dispersed 
c(:,1)=0.005*ones(s,1);       % the run length  
for m=1:s                    % the initital posistions 
    P(1,:,1,1,1)=0+rand(1,s)*(1-(0))';
    P(2,:,1,1,1)=0+rand(1,s)*(1-(0))';
   %P(3,:,1,1,1)= .2*rand(s,1)';
end
```

Now I want to insert this code in my tex file and I do not want to type or copy/paste it again. This is how it can be done provided `ff16.m`, my `main.tex` file and `mcode.sty` are all in the same folder:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{My program}
\lstinputlisting{ff16.m}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result will be:

[image]

Without figure environment, the code will have a box. Since you wanted to float this code like a figure, I have just used `figure` environment and every thing (that should work for a figure like a caption) should work as expected.

Better way to present a code would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
%\caption{My program}
\lstinputlisting[caption=My code here]{ff16.m} % note the caption here.
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Advantage here is the caption will read `Listing 1: My code here` instead of `Figure 1:...`. (You can change `Listing 1:` by `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{My program}` to get `My program 1:`)

[image]

Also, note that the long comments are wrapped automatically at the end of the line.

For details, refer to the `mcode.sty` file itself, from the above link (matlab central).

Comment: @Joe: If the answers are useful to you, you may consider accepting it (by clicking the green check mark near the left of the answer). so that it will be useful for others who search for similar things. Also you may consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `listings` package for code snippets

```
texdoc listings
```

A simple MWE follows

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=matlab,frame=single}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=My caption here]
function [] = wordsearch( words, N )

if nargin<1
    words{1} = 'monkey';
    words{2} = 'hippo';
    words{3} = 'girraffe';
    words{4} = 'crocodile';
    words{5} = 'kangaroo';

    N = 20;
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: but we cannot call an mfile in listings environment, is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: @Negin how about `\lstinputlisting`?...

Answer (score 3):

A more recent alternative to `mcode` is the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package, which is built on top of `listings` and more closely mimicks the syntax highlighting offered by the Matlab editor.

If your readers are students of the language, `matlab-prettifier` also allows you to typeset placeholders in Matlab code snippets very easily (see the second listing below).

Because the package is also compatible with `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`, you can use more exotic fonts than typewriter Computer Modern if you so wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\let\ph\snippetPlaceholder
\lstset
{
  style = Matlab-editor,
  escapechar      = ",
}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\lstinputlisting[caption=Sample code from Matlab]{sample.m}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = {Simple syntax example}]
% syntax of the while loop using a placeholder
while "\ph{condition}"
  % do something useful
  if "\ph{something\_bad}"
    break
  end
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah if combined with this .... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115132/matlab-like-command-box :P

Comment: @percusse You don't get the same kind of highlighting when you call the help from the command line, actually. But I like Alan's answer :)

Comment: @jub0bs is there any way to remove the numbers that comes up to the left of the output?

Comment: @ZenoSan Easy: instead of `\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}`, use `\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Works