# MATLAB like command box

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, mdframed

hello i am trying to set up style for script box.

so far i got 
`\begin{script*} >> help \end{script*}`
working and displaying [image]

i want final version to look some what similar to this picture

[image]

and have second comment that will use more or less same environment

for example

[image]

i'm sure that it can be done with latex, but i don't have enough experience and knowledge.

any help will be appreciated thank you!

**[UPDATE]**
HERE is the final version that i have decide to stay with, it uses tikz and mdframed
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{topBlue}{RGB}{42,93,147}
\definecolor{bottomBlue}{RGB}{10,60,113}
\definecolor{sideline}{RGB}{235,235,237}
\definecolor{frameBlue}{RGB}{17,74,135}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\triangcirc}{\tikz{
\node[draw=frameBlue,inner ysep=4pt,
      color=frameBlue,
      top color=topBlue,
      bottom color=bottomBlue,
      text=white,
      align=flush left,
      font=\textbf\textsf,
      text width=\textwidth] (a) {Command Window};
\node[circle,white,draw,inner sep=3pt] (c) at ([xshift=-3mm]a.east) {};
\node[isosceles triangle,
      white,
      fill,
      rotate=-90,
      anchor=apex,
      isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
      inner sep=1.2pt] (t) at ([yshift=1.5pt]c.south) {};}}

\mdfdefinestyle{commandline}
{leftmargin=0pt, rightmargin=0pt,innerleftmargin=-0.5pt,innerrightmargin=7.5pt,
 middlelinecolor=frameBlue,
 middlelinewidth=1.2pt,
 frametitlerule=false,
 backgroundcolor=white,
 frametitle={\triangcirc},
 frametitleaboveskip=-0.5pt,
 frametitlebelowskip=0pt,
 singleextra={\draw[sideline,line width=12pt] 
      ($(O)+(7pt,1pt)$) -- ($(O|-P)+(7pt,-\mdfframetitleboxtotalheight)-(0,1pt)$);
      \node[inner sep=0pt,color=black]at ($(O)+(7pt,9pt)$) {$\scriptstyle f\!x$}; }
}

\lstnewenvironment{script} {\lstset{language=Matlab,xleftmargin=5mm,basicstyle=\footnotesize,,breaklines=true,aboveskip=-2pt,belowskip=0pt}} {}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=commandline]{script}

\begin{document}
\begin{script}
>> help sin
 sin    Sine of argument in radians.
    sin(X) is the sine of the elements of X.

    See also asin, sind.

    Overloaded methods:
       sdpvar/sin
       codistributed/sin
       gpuArray/sin

    Reference page in Help browser
       doc sin

>> 
\end{script}

\end{document}
```

and THANKS FOR BOTH ANSWERS!!!

Comment: Have a look at the `mdframed` package. I don't know it very well, but IIRC it provides a lot of nice frames. You could try to combine it with e.g. the `listings` package.

Comment: @Uhh. That can be very easily done with PythonTeX for Python command shell. Maybe you can e-mail the author to see how is done.

Comment: Incase you want exactly "MATLAB like command box" a good screenshot capture in `.png` might be one of many ways.

Comment: have a look at the `tcolorbox` package too...

Comment: Which version do you use.

Comment: @Marco Daniel. personally i prefer Tikz version for it's look , but i'm working right not on creating environment such that, in my main file i can simply type \begin{scrip}>> help...\end{script}, and it will produce this window for me.

Comment: Please see the edit of Alan's answer.

Comment: @Marco Daniel. that is amazing thank you very much :)

Comment: Why does this not work with a standalone document i.e. by replacing article to standalone i receive the following error: Missing \endgroup inserted \begin{script}

Comment: @Kate I will assume that it has to do with what is included in "standalone" packages, rules. You may need to add additional in order to make it work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a version using `mdframed`.

**Revised version**

I've updated the answer to include the grey bar that was missing from the earlier answer, and I've removed the dependency on an Apple font by using [percusse's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) code for the circled triangle. Because `mdframed` allows breaks across pages, this solution will be slightly more flexible than a solution that puts the code in a TikZ node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{.11,.23,.60}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\triangcirc}{\tikz{
\node[circle,white,draw,inner sep=3pt] (c) {};
\node[isosceles triangle,
      white,
      fill,
      rotate=-90,
      anchor=apex,
      isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
      inner sep=1.5pt] (t) at ([yshift=0.5pt]c.south) {};}}

\mdfdefinestyle{commandline}
{leftmargin=5pt, rightmargin=10pt,innerleftmargin=15pt,
 middlelinecolor=DarkBlue,
 middlelinewidth=2pt,
 backgroundcolor=white,
 frametitle={Command Window\hfill\triangcirc},
 frametitlefont={\normalfont\sffamily\color{white}\hspace{-1.25em}},
 frametitlebackgroundcolor=DarkBlue,
 singleextra={\draw[black!20,line width=12pt] node[inner sep=0pt,color=black]
      at ($(O)+(7pt,9pt)$) {$\scriptstyle f\!x$} 
      ($(O)+(7pt,1pt)$) -- ($(O|-P)+(7pt,-\mdfframetitleboxtotalheight-1pt)$);}}

\newmdenv[style=commandline]{cmdline}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab,basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{cmdline}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt]
>> help sin
 sin    Sine of argument in radians.
    sin(X) is the sine of the elements of X.

    See also asin, sind.

    Overloaded methods:
       sdpvar/sin
       codistributed/sin
       gpuArray/sin

    Reference page in Help browser
       doc sin

>> 
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{cmdline}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

---

The following code simplify the complete method by defining on environment `script` which results in your required output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{.11,.23,.60}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\triangcirc}{\tikz{
\node[circle,white,draw,inner sep=3pt] (c) {};
\node[isosceles triangle,
      white,
      fill,
      rotate=-90,
      anchor=apex,
      isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
      inner sep=1.5pt] (t) at ([yshift=0.5pt]c.south) {};}}

\mdfdefinestyle{commandline}
{leftmargin=5pt, rightmargin=10pt,innerleftmargin=15pt,
 middlelinecolor=DarkBlue,
 middlelinewidth=2pt,
 frametitlerule=false,
 backgroundcolor=black!10!white,
 frametitle={Command Window\hfill\triangcirc},
 frametitlefont={\normalfont\sffamily\color{white}\hspace{-1.25em}},
 frametitlebackgroundcolor=DarkBlue,
 singleextra={\draw[black!20,line width=12pt] 
      ($(O)+(7pt,1pt)$) -- ($(O|-P)+(7pt,-\mdfframetitleboxtotalheight)-(0,1pt)$);
      \node[inner sep=0pt,color=black]at ($(O)+(7pt,9pt)$) {$\scriptstyle f\!x$}; }
}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{script} {\lstset{language=Matlab,basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,breaklines=true,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}} {}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=commandline]{script}

\begin{document}
\begin{script}
>> help sin
 sin    Sine of argument in radians.
    sin(X) is the sine of the elements of X.

    See also asin, sind.

    Overloaded methods:
       sdpvar/sin
       codistributed/sin
       gpuArray/sin

    Reference page in Help browser
       doc sin

>> 
\end{script}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: this code does look smaller and more simpler, but i was not able to compile it due to "Apple Symbols". And another think that i'm not sure how to add left side line (grey with fx inside.)

Comment: Do you think `mdframed` helps incase of a longer of screen output(may be multiple `help sin` `help cos` etc..) version ?

Comment: @vveiliev I've updated the code to add the missing elements and removed the need for the Apple font. (No longer needs XeTeX either).

Comment: @texenthusiast Yes, `mdframed` can break across pages, which might be useful for longer listings.

Comment: it does look good but 2 things , there is some offsets introduced when zoom-in as well as black borders, another think that i cant find how to set frame-background colour to blend from one colour to another.

Comment: @vveliev: The background color is controlled by the option `backgroundcolor`. Where do you have an offset?

Comment: @ Marco Daniel. Well if you zoom in , to inside of top left corner you can see that grey color slightly overlaps with frametitle

Comment: @vveliev: Fixed the dimension in the example.

Comment: @vveliev I think it's fair to accept this answer instead of mine. It's great and also involves the author of mdframed who confirmed to include these in the manual for a future release. Note that mdframed has the option to use TikZ as the underlying graphics engine hence it's not quite a choice between TikZ and mdframed.

Comment: @percusse, :) will it's really is hard to pick. Both answers are good and involve each other.

Answer (score 23):

Just a quick cook-up if mdframed doesn't have a direct support for this (I doubt that it doesn't though). The basic functionality is there such as shrinking via depending on the vertical size etc. but I didn't test it extensively and I got lazy for the triangle of the $fx$ part. Probably a better font would make it look way nicer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,listings,amssymb}
\lstset{language=Matlab,basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,inner ysep=3pt,
      top color=blue!60!black,
      bottom color=blue,
      text=white,
      align=flush left,
      font=\tiny\ttfamily,
      text width=\textwidth] (a) {Command Window};
\node[circle,white,draw,inner sep=1.9pt] (c) at ([xshift=-3mm]a.east) {};
\node[isosceles triangle,
      white,
      fill,
      rotate=-90,
      anchor=apex,
      isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
      inner sep=0.8pt] (t) at ([yshift=0.5pt]c.south) {};

\node[
      anchor=north west,
      minimum width=\textwidth-3mm,
      align=flush left,
      font=\tiny\ttfamily,
      text width=\textwidth-3mm,
      inner sep=0
     ] (l) at ([xshift=3mm]a.south west)
    {%
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt]
>> help sin
 sin    Sine of argument in radians.
    sin(X) is the sine of the elements of X.

    See also asin, sind.

    Overloaded methods:
       sdpvar/sin
       codistributed/sin
       gpuArray/sin

    Reference page in Help browser
       doc sin

>> 
\end{lstlisting}%
};

\filldraw[fill=blue!10,draw=white] ([yshift=-0.3pt]a.south west) rectangle (l.south west);
\draw ([xshift=0.3pt]a.south west) rectangle ([xshift=2mm+0.7pt]l.south east);
\node[anchor=south east,inner xsep=0.5pt,inner ysep=1pt] (f) at (l.south west) {$\scriptstyle f\!x$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]