# copying a screenshot image with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a package that can be used to draw images that resemble a screenshot with tikz. For example, if I take the following screenshot

[image]

Is there a package that does this in tikz or is it a case of drawing the appropriate shapes from scratch?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/how-to-export-svg-to-tikz/60666#60666. What you're asking for is very difficult, and I doubt a really good solution exists. If there were one, I would already have "vectorised" all my pictures...

Comment: What's the intended use of such package? Are just trying to get a screenshot that can be scaled arbitrarily? Are you trying to create mock ui elements for illustration? Could the drawing be recreated manually from basic components? Do you need perfect resemblance? Does it need to work on windows only?

Comment: Perhaps something like this is what you are after?  [MATLAB like command box](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115132)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this using either the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) or the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) packages. Here's some example code using `tcolorbox` (some details can be improved, but this is left as an exercise):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{176,209,244}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{212,219,239}
\definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{239,239,239}
\definecolor{red1}{RGB}{187,71,54}

\newtcolorbox{notepad}[1][Untitled]{
freelance,
coltitle=black,
fonttitle=\footnotesize,
frame code={
  \draw[rounded corners=2pt,fill=blue1] 
    ([xshift=-2pt]frame.north west) --
    ([xshift=2pt]frame.north east) --
    ([xshift=2pt,yshift=-2pt]frame.south east) --
    ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=-2pt]frame.south west) -- cycle;
  \node[anchor=north west,xshift=1.5pt] 
    at (frame.north west)  
    {\includegraphics[height=10pt]{notepad.png}};  
  \node[draw,fill=red1,anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,text width=10pt,minimum height=8pt] 
  at ([xshift=-1.5pt]frame.north east) (close) {};
  \node[draw,fill=gray1,anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,text width=10pt,minimum height=8pt] 
  at ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]close.north west) (minim) {};
  \node[draw,fill=gray1,anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,text width=10pt,minimum height=8pt] 
  at ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]minim.north west) (hide) {};
  \draw[double,fill=gray1] 
    ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=-2pt]minim.center) rectangle 
    ([xshift=2pt,yshift=2pt]minim.center);
  \draw[fill=white] 
    ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-1pt]hide.center) rectangle 
    ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-2.2pt]hide.center);
  \draw[fill=white,rotate=45] 
    ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-0.8pt]close.center) rectangle 
    ([xshift=3pt,yshift=0.8pt]close.center);
  \draw[fill=white,rotate=135] 
    ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-0.8pt]close.center) rectangle 
    ([xshift=3pt,yshift=0.8pt]close.center);
  \draw[draw=none,fill=white,rotate=45] 
    ([xshift=-3pt+\pgflinewidth,yshift=-0.8pt+\pgflinewidth]close.center) rectangle 
    ([xshift=3pt-\pgflinewidth,yshift=0.8pt-\pgflinewidth]close.center);
  },
  title code={
    \draw[fill=gray1] 
      (title.south west) rectangle 
      ([yshift=10pt]title.south east);
    \node[anchor=south west,inner ysep=0pt,xshift=1.5pt] 
      at (title.south west) 
      {\footnotesize File\quad Edit\quad Format\quad View\quad Help};
  },
  bottomtitle=12pt,
interior titled code={
  \draw[fill=white] 
    (interior.north west) --
    (interior.north east) --
    (interior.south east) --
    (interior.south west) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=gray2,draw=gray!30] 
    ([xshift=-7pt,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]interior.north east) rectangle 
    ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=7+\pgflinewidth]interior.south east);    
  \draw[fill=gray2,draw=gray!30] 
    ([yshift=7pt,xshift=\pgflinewidth]interior.south west) rectangle 
    ([xshift=-7pt-\pgflinewidth,yshift=+\pgflinewidth]interior.south east);
  \node[isosceles triangle,fill=black!70,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm, shape border rotate=180, isosceles triangle stretches,scale=0.105] 
    at ([yshift=3.5pt,xshift=4pt]interior.south west) {};      
  \node[isosceles triangle,fill=black!70,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm, shape border rotate=0, isosceles triangle stretches,scale=0.105] 
    at ([yshift=3.5pt,xshift=-11pt]interior.south east) {};      
  \node[isosceles triangle,fill=black!70,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm, shape border rotate=90, isosceles triangle stretches,scale=0.105] 
    at ([xshift=-3.5pt,yshift=-5pt]interior.north east) {};      
  \node[isosceles triangle,fill=black!70,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm, shape border rotate=-90, isosceles triangle stretches,scale=0.105] 
    at ([xshift=-3.5pt,yshift=12pt]interior.south east) {};      
  \draw[fill=gray2,draw=gray!30] 
    ([yshift=7pt,xshift=-7pt]interior.south east) rectangle 
    ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=+\pgflinewidth]interior.south east);
  \fill[gray1!94!black]
    ([yshift=\pgflinewidth,xshift=-\pgflinewidth]interior.south east) --   
    ([yshift=7pt,xshift=-\pgflinewidth]interior.south east) --   
    ([xshift=-7pt,yshift=\pgflinewidth]interior.south east) -- cycle;  
  },
  title={\hspace*{11pt}#1-Notepad},
  height=8cm,
  left=1.5pt,
  right=8.5pt,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{notepad}
text text
\end{notepad}

\begin{notepad}[Document]
text text
\end{notepad}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a second I thought you drew an actual notepad for the icon :) amazing nevertheless

Comment: @percusse LOL! (and some words required to send this comment).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I guess what percusse meant is it looks like a screenshot. And yes, it does!

Comment: @Speravir I meant the notepad in the upper left corner.

Comment: @percusse: Ah, looks nonetheless like a screenshot (Not of Windows 7 though).