# Intersection of equation with code frame in listings package

Tags: listings, framed

I used the listings package with single frame and I had an equation before my code. The problem is that the frame intersects a little with the equation and the output is ugly. This happens both when I leave a blank line bewtween the equation and the code and when I am not. How can I fix that? Why did this happenned?
[image]

Edit I:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle y(t)=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{e^{2t}}{4}+\frac{e^{3t}}{6}$, for $t\ge 0$

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,breaklines=true]
clc;
clear all;
close all;
t=0:0.1:20;
y= 1/12 -exp(2*t)/4 + exp(3*t)/6;
G=tf(1,[2 -10 12]);
[y2, t2]=step(G,t);
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,y);
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t2,y2);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this is MATLAB code.

Comment: If you want to typeset Matlab code, you might want to use the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `\displaystyle` for fractions that are in `inline` math mode. This results in big fractions that extrude below the baseline. Hence this clash.

Without `\displaystyle`:

[image]

They don't clash. Hence if you are using `\displaystyle` you need some more vertical space and we provide that through `aboveskip` from listings. Through `aboveskip` you can adjust the spacing between the listing and the paragraph above it.

Using `aboveskip` with a suitable `dimension`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle y(t)=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{e^{2t}}{4}+\frac{e^{3t}}{6}$, for $t\ge 0$

\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=\baselineskip,frame=single,breaklines=true]
clc;
clear all;
close all;
t=0:0.1:20;
y= 1/12 -exp(2*t)/4 + exp(3*t)/6;
G=tf(1,[2 -10 12]);
[y2, t2]=step(G,t);
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,y);
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t2,y2);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is similarly `belowskip` if you want.

As a side note, since it is matlab code, you may consider [Jubobs matlab-prettifier](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) or `mcode` to typeset these codes. `matlab-prettifier` has good features.  Also refer to [this question and its answers.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53238/11232)

Comment: Thank you very useful. What exactly does `aboveskip` does? Also why is this intersection there in the first place? Shouldn't normally be space between the equation and the frame?

Comment: @Adam I have added some explanation.

Comment: Shouldn't the baseline change when there is `displaystyle` in use? And also when there is `displaystyle` with a table there isn't the same problem although as I understand there should be.

Comment: @Adam Inline math has limitation of baseline skip. Table is different issue.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks for the vote of confidence :)

Comment: @Jubobs Indeed you did good! I myself use `matlab-prettifier` these days instead of `mcode`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `displaymath` environment instead. Then there is no need for any adjustments:

[image]

### Notes:

- I also added `basicstyle=\ttfamily` for the `listsings`. Otherwise, the code, especially `G=` lined didn't look right.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
    y(t)=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{e^{2t}}{4}+\frac{e^{3t}}{6}, \text{ for } t\ge 0
\end{equation*}
%
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,breaklines=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
clc;
clear all;
close all;
t=0:0.1:20;
y= 1/12 -exp(2*t)/4 + exp(3*t)/6;
G=tf(1,[2 -10 12]);
[y2, t2]=step(G,t);
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,y);
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t2,y2);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already use `\ttfamily` in my code along with some other options for highlighting. Here is just an example. Why without the `displaymath` environment the `G=` is like that?